# How to pre-evaluate commands that are problematic for a specific environment?

Tags: macros, captions

More specifically, my problem occurs in the caption environment, but I imagine this applies elsewhere.

I would like to insert the text generated by \suppOrApp and store it in the variable \sOrA:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\title{A caption test}
\author{Some one}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\suppOrApp}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{thesisStyle}}
    {Appendix}
    {Supplementary}
}
\newboolean{thesisStyle}
\setboolean{thesisStyle}{false} % Might want to reconsider this here.

\def \sOrA {\suppOrApp}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\blindtext
\sOrA
\blindtext}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

What is the simplest or best way to do this?

Comment: Your command is fragile; use `\DeclareRobustCommand\sOrA{\suppOrApp}` so you don't have to `\protect` it in mobile arguments.

Comment: oops sorry @GonzaloMedina just saw your comment:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No problem :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, happy to upvote that as an answer as well. I also saw it too late. What I ended up doing was removing \sOrA and just doing: \DeclareRobustCommand\suppOrApp{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{thesisStyle}}
    {Appendix}
    {Supplementary}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is fragile (because of the use of `\ifthenelse` so needs `\protect` if used in a moving argument such as caption:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\title{A caption test}
\author{Some one}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\suppOrApp}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{thesisStyle}}
    {Appendix}
    {Supplementary}
}
\newboolean{thesisStyle}
\setboolean{thesisStyle}{false} % Might want to reconsider this here.


% This has additional space:
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textbf{\suppOrApp Table}}
% But this would work fine.
%\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textbf{Supporting Table}}

\def \sOrA {\suppOrApp}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\blindtext
\protect\sOrA
\blindtext}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case it's not a missing `%`.

Comment: @egreg Yes just spotted that but it is fragile...

Comment: Thanks! did not know about \protect. Additionally, I don't need to use \def to evaluate the command.

Comment: `\def` _never_ evaluates the command, it just made another  macro that expanded to your first macro when used.